# Objective function: linear programming

Tags: operations-research

The following simultaneous nonlinear equations are to be solved:

$$y=e^x$$

$$y=x(1+x)$$

Define an objective function that can be maximized to obtain a solution to these equations.

Sketch x vs F(x) and identify the optimal solution (x*) graphically.

I don't know if I'm supposed to set the two y equations equal to each other and solve for x? How do I get an objective function from this?

Comment: Is your optimization problem supposed to be a linear program?

Answer (score 1):

Well if we want to find a solution to the equations you have given then let the objective function be

\begin{align}
F(x) = -|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|
\end{align}

where $f_1(x) = e^x$ and $f_2(x)= x(x+1)$. Then maximising $F$ is equivalent to minimising the distance between the two functions which will yield a solution to the system. You can quickly sketch the function in question by first sketching the function inside the absolute value sign and then reflecting about the x-axis whenever it goes below zero. Then "flip" it and you should get an idea where the solution is (the maximum of the resulting function).